# Selenium Parallel execution using multi thread browser bring front issue

Tags: multithreading, selenium-webdriver

Chrome browser is getting bring front while running selenium scripts parallels using multi thread concept hence focus of screen is losing and failing most of test cases. could any one advise if anything can be done for not to bring front browser

Comment: What did you try, what are you testing and what's the *actual* problem? You can't use a single browser tab from multiple threads. Selenium doesn't replace the browser, it drives it. If you want to execute multiple tests or scrape multiple sites you'll have to create multiple IWebDriver instances. Finding an element doesn't care about focus either.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best options is to run headless when you're running the tests in parallel:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks you for Swift response, I already tried running using headless , but stale element exception is raising

Comment: if the failing tests is passing when you run it as a single test, and fails when running in parallel, then this means that you are sharing the webdriver across tests. Make sure then that your tests are having a unique instance of webdriver.